# Sending email through PhpMailer doesn't return response to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, debugging, phpmailer

I'm using PhpMailer to send emails from a php/Javascript and it's working BUT is not returning the `success: function(response)`.

My javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('.pendente').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'send_email.php',
                async: true,
                data: dados,
                context: this,
                success: function(response) {
                    alert("Ok!");
                    $(this).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-warning');

                }
            });

});
```

My send_email.php:

```
<?php 
include "ligacao.php"; //connection string to BD

$encweb = $_POST['enc'];
$datapendente = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$texto = "'Pendente em ".$datapendente;
$texto = $texto."'";

$sql="UPDATE Texoleo.dbo.bo set bo.logi2=0, bo.logi4=1 ";
$sql=$sql.", bo.dataopen='".$datapendente."', bo.u_msgshist=";
$sql=$sql." concat(".$texto.", char(13)+char(10))+(cast(bo.u_msgshist as nvarchar(600))) ";
$sql=$sql." where bo.fref='".$encweb."'";

$result = odbc_exec($connect, $sql);
/**** Fim sql ****/


/**** Enviar email ****/

$clientenome = $_POST['nome'];
$clienteemail = $_POST['email'];

include('lib/class.phpmailer.php');
include('lib/class.smtp.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                              

$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'myhost.com';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                              

$mail->Username ='user@user.com';
$mail->Password = 'mypassword'; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                           
$mail->Port = 587;                                  

$mail->setFrom('my@email.com', 'Me');
$mail->addAddress('customer email', 'Customer name');

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  
$texto = 'bla, bla, bla ';
$mail->Subject = 'My subject';
$mail->Body    =  $texto;
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
};

$response = array("success" => true);
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Testing the same Javascript without the `$mail->send()` it returns success true, but with `$mail->send()` it does what it has to do (some SQL updates and email sent) but it doesn't return the success `true` to continue doing the Javascript code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in my comment:

The debug output is messing with the JSON format. Disable it by setting `SMTPDebug = 0`, and remove any other non-JSON output too.

You can usually see this kind of thing happening if you inspect the responses to your XHR requests in your browser’s dev tools.

Comment: Life saver. I knew my JSON was correct. There was some echo output I had to remove after setting the debug to off and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Also you might want to set $mail->Debugoutput = 'error_log'
By default it is set to 'echo'.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with SMTPDebug=2. It should be SMTDebug=0 as proposed by @synchro . Many thanks also to Атанас Атанасов for his help. 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

Answer (score 0):

I noticed there are few echoes which cause the problem. Your response looks like this:

```
Message has been sent
{"success":true}
```

And you want it to be look like bellow, so javascript can handle it as a **json**, not string:

```
{"success":true, "msg":'Message has been sent'}
```

You should make your messages as variable so you can pass them with response.

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
    $msg = 'Message could not be sent: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    $msg = 'Message has been sent'; 
};

$response = array("success" => true, 'msg' => $msg);
echo json_encode($response);
```

You can use Network tab in Developer Tools to what is the request and response payload of your ajax calls.

Also you should better set content type header to json.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: Thank you for your really quick reply, but already tried setting the header and without any echoes from $mail->send(). Just the $mail->send() function and it doesn't work either. It sends the email but doesnt do whatever is in ajax after . :-(

Comment: Help me figure it out (newbie). How can I see it?

Comment: Open Developer Tools of you browser and there is Network tab. There you can see all the info about every request your site makes.

Comment: Hi found one error: _SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 5 of the JSON data_ . 
Line 1: 2018-04-18 14:01:50 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 220 Welcome to....
(I don't know if it this that you are looking for)

Comment: Can you try this ..

    if($mail->send()) {
$response = array("success" => true);
}
else {
$response = array("success" => false);
}
echo json_encode($response);

Comment: You’ve got debug output enabled which will mess up the JSON output. Disable it with `SMTPDebug = 0`.

Comment: "Disable it with SMTPDebug = 0" How?

Comment: _Can you try this .. if($mail->send()) { $response = array("success" => true); } else { $response = array("success" => false); } echo json_encode($response);_ Same result :-(

Comment: $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

Comment: Hey @Synchro can you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

What version of jQuery are you using?

If you are ussing jQuery 3.0+ you should use .done() instead of .success() as it is deprecated.

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.