# Using an HTML jquery ajax request in PHP mailer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, phpmailer

I have some html form with jQuery and ajax, in server side I use php mailer to response the request that I've made. Mail send and ajax response are good but I wrote another code to open another page when returning response succeeds but it won't work.

Here's my jQuery ajax request code:

```
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        var mylink   = "xx........";    
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                 url: mylink,
                 type: 'post',
                 data: formData,  
                 dataType : 'json',
                 encode   : true,
                 success: function(data) {  
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    if(JSON.stringify(data.success)=="true"){
                        location.href = "mailconfirm.html";
                    }else{
                        $(".info").html("<p class='alert alert-warning'>"+JSON.stringify(data)+"</p");
                    }
                 },
                 cache: false,
                 contentType: false,
                 processData: false
             });
```

The returning data in my console log:

[image: response in console.log]

I want the browser go to mailconfirm.html if the mail has been successfully sent, in another page I use the same code (`location.href =` ) without phpmailer and it works good.

I'm aware if in another page I don't get "response payload" value, that (in this page) the value of response payload are containing smtp mail send response. How can I resolve this?

Comment: This comparison: `JSON.stringify(data.success)=="true"` will never be true. I think you intend to do: `data.success == "true"`?

Comment: thanks for your reply I have try your solution its still act same... :D , and in another page check if true value with JSON.stringify it also work.., but realy big thanks for your reply

Comment: Have you checked what is actually in the responses? If for example you have debug output enabled in PHPMailer it will break all your XHRs. Use your browser dev tools to check.

Comment: im sorry ... @Synchro how to debug output enabled in PHPMailer? i'm quite new for this, in my php scripts theres no error show the mail send successfully, but in my browser console(the client html page) i got the "response payload" , that containing mail send data (the HTML page not in the server).

Comment: hi @Synchro , i read your solution in another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49900902/sending-email-trough-phpmailer-doesnt-return-response-to-javascript ,  to changing smtpdebug=0 , not work either,but when i check the json format from the php script(my PHPscript to send mail) like you suggest in that post (there a output not in json format) its work like charm :D thanks a lot, thank you so much